# Accessing locally stored active storage files in production

Tags: rails-activestorage

I have an rails 6 app running on Heroku that is used to capture videos and upload them. A typical use case is for the user to make a video then upload it. I am successfully using `active storage` with direct uploads to Amazon S3 for this.

However, the user can be on a slow mobile link so wants to upload the video later when they are on a broadband link.  The model that I am using is as follows:

```
class Lesson
   has_one_attached :video
   ...
end
```

The user makes a video by clicking a link generated by this code:

```
<%= simple_form_for@lesson) do |f| %>
   <%= f.file_field :video, id: 'video_file', direct_upload: true %>  
   ...
<% end %>
```

If inspect `lesson.video` after it the file has been attached but before the form is submitted, it appears to have a data structure that includes the address of the local file that stores the video.

Can I somehow save the information in `lesson.video` and then upload the file to Amazon S3 at a later time?

Comment: use scheduler or  sidekiq and give option like upload later or on specific date and time .

Comment: If it was done this this way, wouldnt the active job blob have to be uploaded to heroku immediately in order that the job can can complete when scheduled?  If that is the case, it means that it is still using the low mobile link to upload?

Answer (score -1):

To improve S3 upload speed we need to do following:

- Enable Transfer Acceleration on your S3 bucket.
- Change your application to upload files in [multiple parts](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/CHANGELOG.md), using S3 Multipart Upload, and use multi-threading to upload more than one part at a time.

[Enable Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html)

[S3 Multipart Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html)

Comment: That will be useful if I cannot find the answer to my question.